# Does the .user.ini file work for subdirectories?

Tags: php, php-5.3

Does the `.user.ini` file that controls folder specific PHP settings also descend into the subfolders?

I was reading a few websites and they suggest that it does (albeit there is not alot of information about it), however I've found that if I run a script from a subfolder, it doesn't use the settings from the `.user.ini` file.

Am I missing something or is it only meant to be for the same folder that the script is executing from? If so, is there a way to make php scripts look for the `.user.ini` file from the parent folder etc?

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it should work. However, I had the same issue with .user.ini files not setting php_value's recursively. According to official (and short) documentation on php.net they should work recursively (as .htaccess did):

> PHP scans for INI files in each directory, starting with the directory
>   of the requested PHP file, and working its way up to the current
>   document root (as set in $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).
>   **In case the PHP file is outside the document root, only its directory is scanned.**

What I have found out is that Apache configuration had **one trailing slash too much** which caused .user.ini files not to work recursively.

Take a look at your *phpinfo()*, specifically *SCRIPT_FILENAME* variable. Notice two slashes - where should be just one:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = //home/site/public_html/phpnfo.php
```

The reason for this was coming from apache config, which contained one trailing slash too much.

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/lib/php/php-fpm.sockets/site.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
    </FilesMatch>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Apache config doesn't include trailing slashes for directories so instead of **fcgi://localhost/** this should be written as **fcgi://localhost** like this:

```
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/lib/php/php-fpm.sockets/site.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
</IfModule>
```

After change, restart Apache/php-fpm and you are set.

**Update:** As it turns out, trailing slash errors in Apache config are still common thing and can lead to different errors and bad php practices (eg set in `DocumentRoot /var/www/web/` ).

Comment: You've just saved me from such a headache. I've been troubleshooting this issue for half a year!

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: You're a hero! Didn't catch that trailing slash, it works now!

Comment: For some reason (I don't know) this problem exists on Windows PHP but was fixed in PHP 7.3.19 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69436

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of reading "few websites" I would sugest reading PHP manual:

> Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for .htaccess-style INI files on
>   a per-directory basis. **These files are processed only by the
>   CGI/FastCGI SAPI**. This functionality obsoletes the PECL htscanner
>   extension. If you are using Apache, use .htaccess files for the same
>   effect.
>
> **In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each
>   directory, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and
>   working its way up to the current document root** (as set in
>   $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']). In case the PHP file is outside the
>   document root, only its directory is scanned.

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Comment: Well that functionality is not working then. It is only picking up the `.user.ini` file if it exists in the current directory of the script. This is using virtual directories with IIS. It may be different when installed on apache?

Comment: " If you are using Apache, use .htaccess files for the same effect."

Comment: ...and if I'm not using Apache? I ended up using the main `php.ini` and using the `[PATH=xxx]` to set the configuration which has propagated to the subdirectories.

Comment: For me, it only works at maximum 2 level deep of folder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628499/user-ini-file-only-works-2-level-of-folder
http://localhost/test/lv2 works but http://localhost/test/lv2/lv3 not working.