# .user.ini file only works 2 level of folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have Apache with PHP installed (on Windows) and run as fastCGI.
My **php.ini** has this value, `upload_max_filesize` = 2M.

I override this value in **.user.ini** file to 10M.

Every thing works fine until the folder level is deeper than 2 level.
For example:
If I put **.user.ini** file into www root.
http://localhost/ -> `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` result is 10M
http://localhost/test -> `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` result is 10M
http://localhost/test/lv2 -> `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` result is 10M
http://localhost/test/lv2/lv3 -> `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` result becomes 2M which is **php.ini** value and this folder has no **.user.ini** file.

These are not in virtual directory.

How to make **.user.ini** file works in deeper level of folder?

---

edited: add httpd.conf for php

```
<IfModule fcgid_module>
    FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "C:/wwwserver/php/php5.6"
    FcgidInitialEnv PATH "C:/wwwserver/php/php5.6;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;C:/Program Files (x86)/ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16;"
    FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
    FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
    FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
    FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
    FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"
    FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000
    FcgidIOTimeout 64
    FcgidConnectTimeout 16
    FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500
    FcgidMaxRequestLen 30000000

    <Files ~ "\.php$">
        AddHandler fcgid-script .php
        FcgidWrapper C:/wwwserver/php/php5.6/php-cgi.exe .php
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

Reference: https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=22141

Comment: I had similar problems due to extra trailing slash in Apache config. It changed $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] which ultimately lead to freaky .user.ini behaviour. Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/41879334/528020

Comment: @seven But I'm on Windows.

Comment: on windows, you can have this issue as well. check phpinfo and report back what does SCRIPT_FILENAME say.

Comment: C:/Users/xxx/my-sites/info.php As I said and it seems nothing wrong. I don't think it is because slash in my case. And there is no extra slash in the configuration.

Comment: I wonder if this happens on 7.0 on windows as well? It seem that there are some open issues with current implementation of php_cgi_ini_activate_user_config. they kinda explain your situation https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69436. Also this, however I was unable to find specific bug fixes in bug track http://serverfault.com/questions/441855/custom-php-ini-files-for-iis7

Comment: @seven This was fixed since PHP 7.3.19 thanks. :-)