# .user.ini for sendmail_path will not apply to subdirectories

Tags: php, linux, ini

I have confirmed the config

```
sendmail_path = xxxx
```

in `.user.ini` will not apply to subdirectories only the parent directly. **( the other configs will )**

If I place another `.user.ini` in subfolder, it works. `php.ini` in subfolder will work as well.

That will lose the purpose of using .user.ini. for me in this case. May I ask is this PHP bug ?? and the possible reason of cause?

My environment is Linux with WHM, php version 5.6.

Comment: `.user.ini` files are _per directory_, by definition: ["Since PHP 5.3.0, PHP includes support for configuration INI files on a per-directory basis."](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) Translation: they do not cascade.

Comment: It should read file in subdirectory but will apply the parent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226055/does-the-user-ini-file-work-for-subdirectories

Comment: No, I think you have that backward: settings do not cascade down, they percolate up.

Comment: Then will you explain why only "sendmail_path" is not being set?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding you. I've made an answer with my understanding of how `.user.ini` files work. Your scenario sounds like the converse of how I'd expect `.user.ini` to work.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Given this structure:

```
.
└── a
    ├── a.php
    ├── b
    │   ├── b.php
    │   └── .user.ini   <== [1]
    └── .user.ini  <== [2]
```

`b.php` will see settings from [1] merged with [2], where values in [2] *replace* those from [1]. `a.php` will see settings only from [2].

Comment: Hi My case is I dont have [1], so b.php will load [2] but only sendmail_path is not being overwritten.

Comment: I see now. I was misled by the discussion of `.user.ini`: it's not involved at all.

Answer (score -1):

`sendmail_path` is [defined](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path) as being `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`, meaning it can only be set in the *system* level settings file, e.g. `php.ini`.

Comment: Then, yes, this sounds buggy.

Comment: Looks like it might be a variation of [bug #50374](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50374).